# Using Android phone to control a raspberry pi nintendo 64 emulator

Tags: game-controllers

Say I make a nintendo 64 emulator on a raspberry pi 4, and I want to use my phone as a wireless controller ether over bluetooth or WiFi.

I doubt that any Android software would have support for linux, let alone support an N64 emulator.

So what would be the best course of action here, make a python translator that catches the signal sent by the phone, reads it, then simulates button presses on the raspberry? If anyone has a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: 1. Use your favorite search engine for "android N64 emulators". As results exist, someone has done it (but probably depends on how powerful is your phone). 2. Sending & capture signals from a Android device will add latency, but there are apps out there to emulate bluetooth/wifi controller - again use search. 3. You may have a better fit at [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=bluetooth+controller) for specific RPi questions.

Comment: @Morrison Chang I've done some googling, I'm just looking for an android controller app that has at least basic linux support, and I can't exactly emulate n64 from a phone and then stream it to my tv, that's complicating a simple problem. I don't mind the latency, and I'm not asking questions about a raspi.

Comment: You should identify make/model/OS version of what phone(s) you have. If you want to use a Android device as a wireless controller, one options is to use a custom ROM to make your device a Bluetooth HID (Human Interface Device) which can connect to RPi4. Another might be to use VNC to connect with RPi. Personally I would just get a [RPi/RetroPie supported gamepad](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Logitech-Controller/) for the tactile feel over a glass screen (and documentation).

Comment: Somehow missed in [RetroPie - Virtual Gamepad](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Virtual-Gamepad/) and/or [Mobile Gamepad](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Mobile-Gamepad/) which uses the mobile browser/Chrome browser as a gamepad. Don't know how well that works, but is an option.

Comment: The chrome browser controller seems promising, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Android 9 added support for the Bluetooth HID Device Profile which can be used to make a Android device behave like a HID gamepad:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHidDevice

The Bluetooth HID profile isn't available on all devices, you can use the Bluetooth HID Profile Tester app to see if it's supported:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rdapps.bluetoothhidtester&hl=en_US&gl=US

I've had some luck using ginkage's GamePad app:

https://github.com/ginkage/GamePad